# Unexpected cell formatting behaviour in XlsxWriter

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

Using xlsxwriter for spreadsheet creation.  Set up the format:

```
fmt_title = self.workbook.add_format({
    'font_name': 'FreeSans',
    'font_size': 14,
    'font_color': '#0066B3',
    'bold': True,
})
```

I applied the format to a merged row then changed the font-size (with the intent of writing another row with a smaller font size)

```
self.worksheet.merge_range('A1:G1', 'Font Size SHOULD be 14',fmt_title)
fmt_title.set_font_size(12)
self.worksheet.merge_range('A2:G2', 'Font Size SHOULD be 12',fmt_title)
```

Problem I am running into is after changing the font-size, all rows with the applied format change to a font-size of 12.  Why does the format change AFTER i have written then row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key thing to realize is that writing of the actual excel file only starts upon execution of the [`workbook.close()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/workbook.html#close) statement.

So basically your `fmt_title` formatting object is not really 'used' yet during execution of `worksheet.merge_range('A1:G1', 'Font Size SHOULD be 14',fmt_title)`. Merely a reference to the formatting object is stored for later use.

The [xlsxwriter documentation](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/format.html) confirms that what you're seeing is normal behaviour (though admittedly it can be counter-intuitive at first):

> ### Modifying Formats
>
> Each unique cell format in an XlsxWriter spreadsheet must have a
>   corresponding Format object. It isn’t possible to use a Format with a
>   `write()` method and then redefine it for use at a later stage. This is
>   because a Format is applied to a cell not in its current state but in
>   its final state. Consider the following example:
>
> ```
> cell_format = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'font_color': 'red'})
> worksheet.write('A1', 'Cell A1', cell_format)
>
> # Later...
> cell_format.set_font_color('green')
> worksheet.write('B1', 'Cell B1', cell_format)
> ```
>
> Cell A1 is assigned a format which initially has the font set to the
>   color red. However, the color is subsequently set to green. When Excel
>   displays Cell A1 it will display the final state of the Format which
>   in this case will be the color green.